# Java Priority Queues: How to ensure that new nodes are inserted first if natural order (compareTo) is the same?

Tags: priority-queue, comparable, huffman-code, java

So, I am dealing with trees whose compareTo() methods will often evaluate to the same thing, but I need new trees to be inserted before the existing nodes in the PriorityQueue. Right now, it seems that the java implementation of PriorityQueue places new node in random position to similar nodes.

```
while (pq.size() >= 2) {
            System.out.println("Iteration: " + i++);
            printPQ();

            BinaryTree b1 = pq.remove();
            BinaryTree b2 = pq.remove();
            BinaryTree newTree = new BinaryTree(b1, b2);

            //add the newly created tree back into pq
            pq.add(newTree);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

For those wondering, this is for a Huffman Code implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the `compareTo(...)` method. If you would add the creation time as property to your `BinaryTree`, this can than be included to the comparism and ensure the order of newly added elements in the `PriorityQueue`.